# how to join or concat two result in single table

Tags: mysql

I have two sql query

This to find enroll count

```
select im.instituteName,count(*) AS enrollcnt 
from institute_csv_users icu 
Inner JOIN institute_master im ON icu.instituteId=im.id 
WHERE im.status=1 
  and icu.centerId=1 
group by im.id 
order by rl.region_name,im.instituteName ASC
```

and this to find login count

```
select im.instituteName,count(*) AS logincnt 
from institute_csv_users icu 
LEFT JOIN institute_master im ON icu.instituteId=im.id 
where icu.email!='' 
  AND im.status=1 
  AND icu.centerId=1 
group by im.id 
order by rl.region_name,im.instituteName ASC
```

Need result like

```
| Institutename | enrollcnt | logincnt | Loginpercentage
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of similarities between the given two queries.
They can be punched to form one single query.

```
select 
  im.instituteName, 
  count(*) AS enrollcnt, 
  count(case when icu.email != '' THEN 1 END) AS logincnt, 
  (
    count(case when icu.email != '' THEN 1 END)/ count(*)
  )* 100 AS LoginPercentage 
FROM 
  institute_csv_users icu 
  INNER JOIN institute_master im ON icu.instituteId = im.id 
WHERE 
  im.status = 1 
  AND icu.centerId = 1 
GROUP BY 
  im.id 
ORDER BY 
  rl.region_name, 
  im.instituteName ASC
```

As a side note, kindly provide a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk) link for us to work on your SQL related problem.